# Google Analytics for Wordpress Daily limit exceeded

Tags: wordpress, analytics, google-analytics-api

Im using the Google analytics for wordpress plugin for quiet a long time.
Today it shows me error (-23) Then (403)

It seems that I am receiving a `(403) Daily Limit Exceeded` error :

```
Last Error: 2017-09-27 06:53:06: (403) Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A117876012&start-date=yesterday&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3Ahour&quotaUser=u1s1p117876012&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION: (403) Daily Limit Exceeded. The quota will be reset at midnight Pacific Time (PT). You may monitor your quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/quotas?project=65556128745
```

However, when I go to the API console link, I see: `The API "analytics" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it`

How to fix this? Please help me on this ....

Comment: You are likely signed into the wrong Google account. If I go to the same link, I get the same error, as I don't have access to project `65556128745`. But if I simply go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/quotas, it works and loads my default project. You need to be logged into the same Google account that owns the project to access that link. As for the [Daily Limit Exceeded error](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#error_table), this means you've likely hit the 50k requests per day per view.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with many websites. Clear authorization within the plugin and reauthorize again. Should work after that.

Victor